# Unit of measure library for Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is anybody aware of any package/library/script for converting units of measure on a UI level (Input/Output)? Something like the Unity.Localization.LocalizeStringEvent that we need to simply attach to strings. I'm struggling to find one.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@0.7/api/UnityEngine.Localization.Components.LocalizeStringEvent.html